# Difference between Exception(String) and Exception(String,Exception)

Tags: c#, exception

Anyone have any idea about difference between Exception(String) and Exception(String,Exception) in c#

Thanks a lot

Comment: You realize there's documentation on this sort of thing, right?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.exception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is:

- The `Exception(String, Exception)` constructor creates an Exception with an InnerException (Exception) and a message (String)
- The `Exception(String)` constructor create an Exception with only a message (String) and the InnerException is `NULL`

You can check this information here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.exception(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps.